# Spring Framework - JDBC Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been trying to create a simple JDBC login page with spring and I don't know how to fix this one issue. I am entering the correct username and password as it shows in the real database, but it isn't logging me in?

It's supposed to log me in, then forward me to the management page for employees only. But everything turns out to become a login error

**Login Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLoginForm(Model model) {

    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "login";
}

@PostMapping("/processLogin")
public String processLogin(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

    if (userService.findUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) == null) {
        return "/access-denied";
    } else {
        return "/management/dashboard";
    }
}

@GetMapping("/access-denied")
public String accessDenied(Model model) {
    return "access-denied";
}
```

**LOGIN Form (JSP Page):**

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user"
                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/processLogin">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <label for="inputUser">Username: </label> <input name="username"
                            type="text" path="username" id="inputUser" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword">Password: </label> 
                        <input name="username" type="password" path="password"
                            id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                            required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                            Remember Password
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

            </form:form>
```

**USER DAO (Query for a user):**

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional
public User findUser(String username, String password) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Query<User> theQuery = session.createQuery("from User 
    where username=:username", User.class);
    User user = theQuery.getSingleResult();

    session.close();

    if (user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public User() {

}

// and all the getters/setters
```

**Database Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `users` 
VALUES 
('john','{noop}test123',1),
('mary','{noop}test123',1),
('susan','{noop}test123',1);
```

Comment: What happens when you use `{noop}test123` as password or update the db to not have `{noop}` ?.  [NoOpPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/5.0.0.M4/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/crypto/password/NoOpPasswordEncoder.html) is required with Spring security . Password is prefixed with {noop} to indicate to DelegatingPasswordEncoder that NoOpPasswordEncoder should be used . This prefix is not to be saved in db along with password.

Comment: Warning: The way you 'compare' passwords provided by the user, and passwords stored in your database, is NOT secure. Use proper password encoder (e.g., bcrypt).!